# Image src breaks when in another page other than homepage

Tags: html, css

My images are located in

`images/icons/artist_default.png`

So, when I'm on the homepage, the image is shown and if I see the path it looks like this:

`http://localhost:7777/images/icons/artist_default.png`

However, in a users page like this one `http://localhost:7777/user/giorgio-martini` it breaks and the path looks like this:

`http://localhost:7777/user/images/icons/artist_default.png`

As you can see, its wrong, it adds the users parameter before it.. so it breaks.

I don't know how to fix this, I shouldn't add a full path, it doesn't feel right... but how do I make the `img` points to the right place?

Thanks

Comment: What does your img src look like? Have you tried starting it with a `/`? i.e. `src="/images/icons/artist_default.png"`

Comment: wow that fixed it... still i dont understand how it was working on homepage? thx.. add a answer and ill aprove it :)

Comment: Learn about relative paths. https://phpdelusions.net/articles/paths

Answer (score 3, accepted):

start image source with a slash('/'). It means it will always start from the basepath.
Instead of,

```
<img src="images/icons/artist_default.png">
```

use this,

```
<img src="/images/icons/artist_default.png">
```